# SQL query to calculate the exchange rate in the year of transaction

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a requirement to create a report in the below attached format. I have to create two metrics, one for current year exchange rate and another for the year of transaction exchange rate. I have one currency table where currency, and respective exchange rate for each year will be stored. I have defined a join between the fact table and currency table on the basis currency code and added latest exchange rate date in the where clause to calculate the first metric. i.e [Local Amount(USD) in Current Year], I am struggling to find the other metric where we are applying the currency conversion rate from the year of transaction. Can anybody help me here in building the sql?

attached image below.

SQl is below,

```
select  ss.date
,ccy.currency_code
,sum(ss.local_amt)
,sum(ss.local_amt/ccy.exchange_rate ) Loc_amt_curr_yr 
from sales ss 
join currency ccy on ss.currency_code = ccy.code
where ccy.exchange_rate_date in 
    (select max(exchange_rate_date) from currency)
group by date,ccy
```

[Currency table][1]

[report Requirement][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BOvP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf8Si.png

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please don't link to pictures in your question - it makes it much harder to understand your question if the information is not in one place. Just add the information to your question as editable text